# Is it possible to use GroovyPageParser or GroovyPagesTemplateEngine outside of grails

Tags: grails, gradle, gsp

I have created an angular application under grails. I would like to separate it now from grails and make it a gradle application (generation of the final files would be gradle job). However in the interim I would still like to use my taglibs  How can I render gsp under gradle without grails loaded?

TIA

Pascal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is [GSP for Spring Boot](https://github.com/grails/grails-boot/tree/master/grails-gsp-spring-boot) a.k.a Standalone GSP available.

See examples: https://github.com/grails/grails-boot/tree/master/sample-apps/gsp

Example of a standalone Spring Boot groovy script: https://github.com/grails/grails-boot/blob/master/sample-apps/gsp/script/app.groovy (requires currently the provided run_app.sh script for launching)

It doesn't support all Grails taglibraries. Only sitemesh and render taglibs are supported of the Grails core taglibs.
However, you can reuse taglibraries if you annotate them with the grails.gsp.TagLib annotation and register them as beans in the application context that runs the Spring Boot application.